# Proof of the inequality: $\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k^N}\gt\frac{N}{\Gamma(N+1)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

The following inequality seems to hold:
$$\forall N\gt2,\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{1}{k^N}\gt\dfrac{N}{\Gamma(N+1)}$$
Is it possible to prove it analytically? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $\Gamma(N+1)=N!$, so $$\frac{N}{\Gamma(N+1)}=\frac{N}{N!}=\frac{1}{(N-1)!}$$ Why don't prove it by induction?

Comment: given that it would appear $N$ is an integer, we have $\Gamma(N+1)=N!$

Comment: Please never use display-style math in titles.

Comment: @cjferes Hard to prove by induction, since $N$ changes in both the terms and the limits of the sum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\forall N\gt2,\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{1}{k^N}>1\geq\dfrac{N}{\Gamma(N+1)}$$

The second inequality holds because $$\Gamma(N+1)=N!=N\cdot(N-1)!\geq N$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the inequality:
$$\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Na_k\ge\prod_{k=1}^Na_k^{\frac{1}{N}}$$ and putting: $a_k=\dfrac{1}{k}$ we get:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{1}{Nk^N}\ge\left(\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(N+1)^N}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{N}}$$
So we get:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{1}{k^N}\ge\dfrac{N}{\Gamma(N+1)}$$ and for $N\gt2,$
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{1}{k^N}\gt\dfrac{N}{\Gamma(N+1)}$$